# My vs-code take me error - Failed to load jshint library. Install library does not give effect

Tags: visual-studio-code, jshint

[image]

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do?

Comment: Try to close and re-open the Vscode again

Comment: does not help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close and re-open the VSCode again.

If the error still occurs then

You can try installing this extension the [Jshint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.jshint) to your **VS-Code**.

Comment: hmm kind of reinstallation helped.

Comment: And i have trouble in ESlint

Comment: [Info  - 11:51:00 AM] ESLint server is running.
    [Info  - 11:51:05 AM] ESLint library loaded from: 
    C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
    [Warn  - 11:51:05 AM] 
    No ESLint configuration (e.g .eslintrc) found for file: d:\Project 
    Web\JS\Learning 
    JS\task.js
File will not be validated. Consider running 'eslint --init' in the workspace folder 
   Learning JS
   Alternatively you can disable ESLint by executing the 'Disable ESLint' 
   command.

Comment: @ОлегГлущенко Did you try installing the EsLint into the Vscode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: Yes, I installed

Comment: And jshint it was installed. I reinstalled it

Comment: @ОлегГлущенко I'm not sure about this `eslint`. Maybe you can post a new question about this. Since your original question is resolved. You can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g jshint type this in your cmd line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).